# Articles 'the' or without 'the'

Tags: definite-articles

Today, the human population of Madagascar has surpassed 20 million.

Today, human population of Madagascar has surpassed 20 million.

What is correct 'the human' or 'humam'

Comment: As good general guidance, all singular countable nouns should have a determiner. You need to ask yourself the question "Is 'population' countable?"

Comment: @Greybeard In *the murky water*, *water* is not countable, yet a definite article would be required in most (but not all) contexts. There are several more variables: if it's been specifically mentioned, if an adjective is used, and some types of contexts. I wouldn't say that the general guidance you give is more than just a minimum starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the context, has the speaker mentioned *human population* earlier ?

Two cases when *The* article is use:

1. The speaker talking about something he/she has referred to earlier.
2. The speaker is referring something unique (e.g. The United States)

---

You can use the following rule to answer you question

> The definite article, the, is used to refer to a particular member of a group or class. It may be something that the speaker has already mentioned or it may be something uniquely specified. The is the only definite article in English, for both singular and plural nouns.

The above quote is from  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)) wikipedia article.

---

TLDR: **the human population** will be correct usage here as there can only be one human population of Madagascar.

Comment: This is wrong, I'm afraid. The definite article is always required in this sentence. There is only one human population of Madagascar.

Comment: Thanks, edited the answer